# StatelessWidget and ScrollController

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `StatelessWidget`  in flutter that has a `ScrollController` , In a child of this component I have `StatefulWidget` that add `scrollController.addListener` in its `initState`

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Placeholder(), //Complex child
        Placeholder(), //Complex child
        Placeholder(), //
        MyStatefulWidget(
          scrollController: scrollController,
        ) // Complex child
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  const MyStatefulWidget({
    @required this.scrollController,
  });

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('Scroll listener added');
    widget.scrollController.addListener(() {
      print('Scroll position changed');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

My problem is, When `build` of parent of `MyStatelessWidget` executed,sometimes I lost scroll listener
Why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_myStatefulWidget` is calling `build` but not `initState`. Therefore, you are not registering a listener on the new controller.

The solution would be to use a state management solution in order to share the controller between the widgets. Check out the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.

Comment: it's occur in production app too

Comment: The solution is still to use a state management solution. I encourage you to start with Provider if state management is new to you. Although there are other options such as bloc or redux.

Comment: I am sure that `addListener` is called, but the problem in `final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();` is re-instantiated

Comment: Correct. I am saying that `addListener` is not called on the new object after re-instantiation. A stateless widget is only built once, therefore when it is "rebuilt", it is actually re-instantiated which is why the same happens to `scrollController`. A stateful widget however can be rebuilt without being re-instantiated. Therefore, `initState` is not being called, and thus, no listener is added to the new `scrollController`.

Comment: A quick solution is to make `_myStatelessWidget` a stateful widget. Then it could rebuild without re-instantiating `scrollController`, but that wouldn't help you understand the nuances of *Stateful* vs. *Stateless* widgets.